# why are the colors of my JPEG drawing different on my phone then on Krita?

Tags: krita

Ive been struggling with this problem for a while now, and all ive been trying to do to fix it is adding filters on my drawings to make it s similar to the drawing on my laptop. When i finish a drawing on Krita and email it to my phone to phone to post it,the colors are very different, sometimes too yellow, redish, or too dark. At first, i thought it was my laptop but everything was normal, then i decided to download a different program (firealpaca) and doodle something and send it to my phone, it was exactly the same. Ive made a post on this problem but i didnt realize it was Krita and not my laptop. Please help.

Comment: Is the document colour mode CMYK, RGB, or something else? What colour profile are you using to export the jpeg?

Comment: The preceding comment should be taken seriously. Krita has a rich set of possiblities to affect its color handling. In the beginning of a new drawing one should select the proper color mode, probably RGB for onscreen works and a correct color profile. Use sRGB profile if you have not a color calibrated system. Simpler programs assume these without asking. In Krita accidental changes are possible easily.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend that when you finish your work and will save a final art, you convert to sRGB. If you did everything right, used correct profiles (or default ones), it will just work fine. Some programs can't detect correctly the icc profile saved with the image and so show the original color space that maybe in your case can be a linear one maybe. This happens because it is possible to save jpegs with the original color space to preserve colors, embedded with a icc to allow programs color space aware to convert it on the fly to sRGB.

1. Save your work
2. Flatten the image in `ctrl+shift+E`
3. convert the color space to sRGB `image > convert color space...`
4. Save as JPEG

Take care to not overwrite the original image.